# ActiveRecord .save return true but don't save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i'm refactoring my code following the answer to my previous question :
[Inheritance misunderstood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046498/inheritance-misunderstood/30047142#30047142)
(just for information this question is about something else)

so i did create 'Archive' module .

```
module Archive
def self.included(klass)
 klass.instance_eval do
   define_method "save_#{klass.name}_archive" do
     ArchiveLogs.debug("PASS HERE")
     self.becomes "Arch#{klass.name}".constantize
    end
   end
  end
end
```

and i use it just here :

```
     ArchiveLogs.debug("DEV BEGIN")

     ArchiveLogs.debug("DEV inspect content"+content.inspect)
     archived_content = content.save_Content_archive
     ArchiveLogs.debug("DEV inspect archived"+archived_content.inspect)
     test = archived_content.save
     test2 = archived_content.save!


     ArchiveLogs.debug("DEV WORK ?"+test.inspect)
     ArchiveLogs.debug("DEV  WORK 2?"+test2.inspect)
```

and here are my logs

```
 DEV BEGIN
DEV inspect content#<Content id: 1653768, server_path: "20141219/M2014121900660", server_name: "content.html", is_html: 1, checksum: #<BigDecimal:62433c0,'0.1307989417E10',18(27)>, save_date: nil, save_place: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-03-31 11:29:43",  updated_at: "2015-03-31 11:29:43", ts_content: nil>
PASS HERE
DEV inspect archived#<ArchContent id: 1653768, server_path: "20141219/M2014121900660", server_name: "content.html", is_html: 1, checksum: #<BigDecimal:624a9e0,'0.1307989417E10',18(27)>, save_date: nil, save_place: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-03-31 11:29:43",  updated_at: "2015-03-31 11:29:43", ts_content: nil>
DEV WORK ?true
DEV  WORK 2?true
```

content model :

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :information
   attr_accessor :text_content
   include Archive
  . 
  . 
  .#many methods here
  .
  .
end
```

Arch content model :

```
class ArchContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'archive.contents'
  has_many :information, :class_name => 'ArchInformation',foreign_key: 'content_id'
  include Archive
  . 
  . 
  .#many methods here
  .
  .
end
```

as you see , my Archive module does his job. Creating ArchContent object when i give him Content object.

But here is my problem .save return true , but my archived_content isn't store in my database. Why ?

i did read about similars problems on post [Rails save returns true but doesn't save anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930869/rails-save-returns-true-but-doesnt-save-anything)

About a validation problems forcing me to use update_column .

So my question :

Am I forced to use update_column ? or my problem is something else ? how to debug this ? 
Any help apricieted !

Comment: Side note: change `"save_#{klass.name}_archive"` to `"save_#{klass.name.underscore}_archive"` so that it follows the Ruby snakecase method names convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks to @FrederickCheung for his explaination, and for @papirtiger for the `underscore` note,
I think i found a better solution for this issue, you could use `#attributes` which returns a hash with the attributes instead of an object

```
define_method "save_#{klass.name.underscore}_archive" do
  "Arch#{klass.name}".constantize.new attributes.except('id')
end
```

This will return an unsaved object with the attributes, and it will drop the id key so that it follows the normal autoincrement scheme of the other table.

Comment: i've got some references to other models with those id , even relation with public schemat ( for little usefull table like parameters i didn't want to duplicate)  i don't know how my application will react if a don't keep the same id ... and for 'unarchive' functionnalitie that could create problems too , anyway this is for my specific application and needs , but i think this is a good answer for this stackoverflow post ! i'll try several implementation , anyway thank you @FrederickCheung and you MohammadAbuShady (ps: Only one additionnal user can be notified  can't tag you ...)

Comment: @TanguyS you can simply remove the `except('id')` and just keep the `attributes` to get exactly all the fields

Comment: "Arch#{klass.name}".constantize.new attributes drop the id and follows the normal autoincrement (even when i remove the except('id') :/) i'm looking for a way to keep this id

Comment: it should work, cause I used fixed ids in my seeds all the time, maybe you are trying to save a record with an ID that's already used in the database?

Answer (score 2):

`becomes` copies all of the record's state, which in your case is too much: it copies the `new_record` flag (so rails will think this object is persisted in the database when it is in fact not) and it copies the attribute change data (so rails thinks that none of the columns have changed data).

The result is that rails thinks there is nothing new to save and so the call to `save` doesn't do anything. Even if you marked the attributes as dirty it would try to do an update rather than an insert, because `new_record?` will be false. As far as I know there is no public api to set `new_record` so I'm unsure as to how this could be made to work.

Comment: you're right , archived_content.new_record? return false :/ i'm trying to find a way to do the trick because i really like my module solution .. ( i did archived_content = ArchContent.new then archived_content = content.save_Content_archive or @new_record = true ) but for now nothing works ... i'll continue to search, anyway if that's doesn't work , i'll try your solution (posted on my first question ). thank you for your precious help   !

Answer (score 1):

See if your item is valid and if you have any validation errors in your log with this:

```
Rails.logger.info archived_content.valid?
test = archived_content.save
Rails.logger.info archived_content.errors.full_messages
```

And post back the results.

Comment: result in logs :Rails.logger.info archived_content.valid? : true  Rails.logger.info archived_content.errors.full_messages :
[]

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Model's `on_update` hooks. In my case it wasn't really a bug it was an update hook that reset the value I was trying to persist.

So it ended up not being a Rails issue, just an issue with my business logic.